# How to play .flv extension file in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, flv

I want to play .flv extension file in iPhone and iPod. I know iPhone and family doesn't support .flv files. Previously I tried it to change in another format like .mov and .mp4. But online converter reduces the quality of video while changing. Can any body suggest me how to play .flv file without any problem in my iOS application.

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't have the correct codecs to play an FLV. It needs to be reencoded as a .mp4 or .mov file. Something that iOS can actually play.